# Search competition webapp to improve my searching skills?

Tags: web-apps, competition

The best way to become a chess champion is to play chess against champions.

Similarly, I want to improve my search skills, so I need champions to compete against.

Is there a webapp that would allow people to challenge for the **best search query** to a given question?

- What was the largest city of Brazil in 1900?
- Is a French driving license usable in Singapore for a Renault B90?
- ... and lots of other tricky questions

Answers would just be:

- the query (or a few queries, or information hops via reference websites if necessary),
- an explanation if not self-explanatory,
- the answer.

A smart answer uses the right search engine, the right words, the right operators, is short to type, displays the result in the first few links, or even better in summaries.

Ratings could be given by peers or something (a bit like on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com, but the rest of the SE software might not be fit for the purpose)

Open source or not, free or not. I am not looking for books or forums or search tips.

Comment: While waiting for anything better, I created a "Search Golf" site proposition on Area51, but it was closed as "not viable" by Robert Cartaino.